# npm update is not updating the version in package.json file

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am trying to update specific package in my project. I have checked it using `npm outdated` and then I run this command to update this package: `npm update nameofpackage` i.e., `npm update slugify`.

My package.json file is not got updated after that, although when i run npm outdated again it shows no outdated package. It means it got updated but my package.json file still shows the older version of the package.

Please let me know how can I update my package.json file also. I have tried `npm update slugify --save` also but it didn't worked for me.

Comment: _"when i run npm outdated again it shows no outdated package "_ - so what's the problem? That's the expected behaviour. `npm update` will install the latest version that's _already permitted by the semver spec in the package file_, and update the lockfile. E.g. for `slugify` version `^1.2.3`, the latest version 1.6.5 would already be in-range. If you're not familiar with semver, have a look at e.g. https://semver.npmjs.com/.

Comment: Furthermore, also when you run `npm install` it will install the latest package available (with respect to semver). So if for instance your `package.json` contains `"slugify": "^1.0.0"` and the lastest available version is `1.9.9` it will install version `1.9.9` on `npm install` or `npm update`. No need for changing the package.json.

Comment: @derpirscher note if there's a lockfile `npm install` _won't_ necessarily install the latest version, it'll install a specific resolved version. Hence `npm update`, which updates the lockfile to the latest compatible version.

Comment: I use [npm-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates) for that, works like a charm

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The objective of the `npm update` command is to update your `package-lock.json` according to what you have specified in the `package.json` file.
This is the normal behavior.

If you want to update your package.json file, you can use [npm-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates): `npm install -g npm-check-updates`.

You can then use these commands:

1. `ncu` Checks for updates from the package.json file
2. `ncu -u` Update the package.json file
3. `npm update --save` Update your package-lock.json file from the package.json file

Comment: So is this line in the nodejs docs incorrect?  

  

*Since npm version 5.0.0, npm update updates package.json with newer minor or patch versions. Use npm update --no-save to prevent modifying package.json.*

https://nodejs.dev/learn/update-all-the-nodejs-dependencies-to-their-latest-version

Comment: As of npm v8, you have to add `--save` to the `npm update` command to ensure the package.json is also updated.

Comment: Why would someone *not* want their package.json to reflect the latest updates?

Answer (score 7):

## Simple and Recent:

install `ncu` package globally:

```
npm install -g npm-check-updates
```

Then these two following code:

### Check for the latest update:

If you want to update all dependencies regardless of the minor or major update limit (~ , ^ ) in the package.json file run the following code to check first for the available update options:

```
$ ncu
[====================] 4/4 100%

 react          16.8.6  →  18.2.0
 react-dom      16.8.6  →  18.2.0
 react-scripts   3.2.0  →   5.0.1
 typescript      3.3.3  →   4.9.4
```

### Update package.json file:

Run ncu -u to upgrade package.json.

**Note**: the `npm update` only checks for updates respecting semver (see the documentation [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-update).

```
ncu -u
```

Then run `npm update` command to update package-lock.json and optimize dependency update in package.json.

```
npm update --save
```

Finally, run the following command to install packages:

```
npm install
```

**Note**: ncu only update the package.json file.